# MLPClassifier cannot fit the training labels given

Tags: python, scikit-learn

So I have a csv of 20000 records. The very first column is the label column and each row consists of a Letter. The other columns are attributes such as width, height etc. I import it and copy each record into an array

```
with open('Letter.csv') as f:
reader = csv.reader(f)
annotated_data = [r for r in reader]
```

Now I want to split the data into a 80-10-10 split, without using `train_test_split`. So I do:

```
train_test_divide = int(0.8 * len(annotated_data))
X_train, X_test = annotated_data[:train_divide], annotated_data[train_divide:]
```

and similarly for the other 10-10 split. So now I want to copy the label column into its own array so that I can fit it into an MLPClassifier `mlp.fit(X_train, y_train)`.

I have tried:

```
for row in X_train:
y_train = row[0]
```

I get `len` of it is `1`, and `np.shape` is `()` so I know this is already wrong.

So then I tried:

```
y_test = [row[0] for row in X_train]
```

When I print the `len` of this, I get 16000, which is what I wanted. If I print the `np.shape` of this, I get `(16000, )` again, what I wanted. But now, if I try to `mlp.fit(X_train, y_train)` this, I get an error saying `Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('<U32') according to the rule 'safe'`. Is it because `y_train` is storing/not storing the Letter as a String or something? What data type is `y_train` supposed to be storing and how can I fix this?

Is the error stemming from my copying the label column into `y_train`? ANY HELP APPRECIATED

EDIT: first few rows look like:

A | 1 | 3 | 4 | 4 | ...

T | 3 | 5 | 3 | 9 | ...

etc

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you the method I use, which works through pandas and sklearn train_test_split

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('Letter.csv')
labels = df[df.columns[0]] # Column 0 because you say it is the first one, but check this index. 
# Better if you name the columns and call them by name
features = df[df.columns[1:]] # Again, check the content of features

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features, labels, test_size=0.2)
```

If by

> each row consists of a Letter

you mean that each row contains strings, you will probably need to vectorize the strings before feeding them to your ML model though.

Can you post the first few rows from your csv file?

Comment: Sorry I should have said I do not want to use `train_test_split`. I shuffle using a seed. I have also posted an example of what the first 2 rows would look like